# Hangfire: enqueue background job from inside a critical section

Tags: c#, multithreading, critical-section, hangfire, offloading

I'm getting an error trying to enqueue a job inside a lock statement.

```
lock (lockObj)
{
    BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => MyJob());
}
```

It complains to distributed transactions being disabled. But I don't want my locks influence on job processing. If I enable MSDTC, will it hold the lock until job processing done? It's the opposite of what I need.

It is not convenient to move `BackgroundJob.Enqueue()` calls outside of the lock block because it could be inside another method which makes it hard to extract (real cases much more difficult):

```
lock (lockObj)
{
    MainWork();
    AnotherMethod();
    MoreWork();
}

private void AnotherMethod()
{
   BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => MyJob());
   SomeWork();
}
```

Could anyone please suggest refactoring/solution I need here?

Comment: No, lock would be released after enqueuing, not after finishing the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Revealed that the issue was not because of lock but because of using TransactionScope. So the next code did the trick:

```
private void AnotherMethod()
{
   using (var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
   {
       BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => MyJob());
       ts.Complete();
   }

   SomeWork();
}
```